# Filtering Items in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to filter items out of one dictionary where that dictionary contains items of another dictionary.  So, say that I have two dictionary's `dict1` and `dict2` where

```
dict1  = {
    1:{'account_id':1234, 'case':1234, 'date': 12/31/15, 'content': 'some content'},
    2:{'account_id':1235, 'case':1235, 'date': 12/15/15, 'content': 'some content'}
}
dict2 = {
    1:{'account_id':1234, 'case':1234, 'date': 12/31/15, 'content': 'some different content'},
    2:{'account_id':4321, 'case':4321, 'date': 6/12/15, 'content': 'some different content'},
    3:{'account_id':1235, 'case':1235, 'date': 12/15/15, 'content': 'some different content'}
}
```

I would like to match on account_id, case and date and have the output be a third dictionary with matched entries from `dict2` being 1 and 3.

```
out = {
    1:{'account_id':1234, 'case':1234, 'date': 12/31/15, 'content': 'some different content'},
    2:{'account_id':1235, 'case':1235, 'date': 12/15/15, 'content': 'some different content'}
}
```

How would I accomplish this?  I am using Python 3.5

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this (or even searching for a solution) yourself?

Comment: Yes - I have tried looking here: http://treyhunner.com/2016/02/how-to-merge-dictionaries-in-python/ and here: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/dictionary/dictionary-manipulation-in-python.  Perhaps I am missing something quite obvious

Comment: And when you tried to use that information (the code for which you have not shared), your attempt didn't succeed in what way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well then, I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
from itertools import count
from operator import itemgetter
# Set the criteria for unique entry (prevents us from needing to write this twice)
get_identifier = itemgetter("account_id","case","date")

# Create a set of all unique items.
unique_entries = set(map(get_identifier, dict1.values()))

# Get all entries that match one of the unique entries
matched_entires = (d for d in dict2.values() if get_identifier(d) in unique_entries)

# Recreate a new dict together with a counter for items.
out = dict(zip(count(1), matched_entires))
```

For more info about [`count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) and [`itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter), see their respective docs.

Using a set and generator comprehensions ensures efficiency at the highest level.